# Free SQL Server tools

Tags: sql-server

Anyone have an update to date list of Free administrative Tools for SQL Server. There is a forum post on SQLServerCentral but its pretty outdated.

Please provide a link as some vendors do a pretty good job of hiding the free stuff.

Comment: MS SQL Server? or just anything that handles SQL?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of listing them all here, here is a link which contains a lot of free tools and other resources *(SQL Server Management Studio Add-ins; SQL injection tools; Administration; best practices, analysis, health and performance, Database Publishing to hosted servers, Update and Migration; SQL Server Analysis Services; SQL Server Integration Services; SQL Server 2005 BI Development Studio (BIDS); Code formatting ...)*:

[Free SQL Server tools that might make your life a little easier](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/11/20/Free-SQL-Server-tools-that-might-make-your-life-a.aspx) from the sqlteam.com blog.

Maybe you can find  something useful in [my Delicious links for sqlserver+freeware](http://delicious.com/splattne/sqlserver+freeware) too.

Comment: You better back up your delicious links since Yahoo is yanking it.

Comment: @GredD :-) already done.

Answer (score 8):

[SQL Server Management Express](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c243a5ae-4bd1-4e3d-94b8-5a0f62bf7796&displaylang=en) is slick and a great free tool for my limited MS SQL needs.

Answer (score 2):

[Toad](http://www.toadsoft.com/) which is used to manage various SQL databases has a freeware version.

Comment: Yuck, toad is one of the worst pieces of software I've ever used and I had the enterprise version that was like $1,000+ a license and it was still horrible. I can't imagine how bad the freeware version is.

Answer (score 2):

There are some new tools available from my company, Atlantis Interactive, all either free or with free editions.

An IDE with code completion, schema comparison tool and space visualisation tool:
[Atlantis web site](http://www.atlantis-interactive.co.uk)

Edit: @squillman - thanks for the heads up. I can't comment yet, but I've just spent ages working on these, and just trying to make sure they get included in lists of free tools, seeing as I'm giving them away! :)

Comment: Just a heads up, someone flagged this as spam (which generates a downvote).  Generally it's not good practice here to advertise your company, that's my guess as to the reason for the flag.

Comment: At least he's not trying to hide the connection, unlike a few others on this site.

Answer (score 1):

[Query Express](http://www.albahari.com/queryexpress.aspx) is only 100kb and doesn't require an install.  It works with ms sql, oracle and other oledb.

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Internals Viewer](http://www.sqlinternalsviewer.com/) - Allows    you to browse

[SQL Server Fine    Build](http://www.codeplex.com/SQLServerFineBuild) - Best Practices one-click installer tool

[SQL IO GUI](http://www.usaupload.net/d/4qmkm6bg5k4) - GUI    Tool for SQIO

[DMV Stats](http://www.codeplex.com/sqldmvstats) -    Collect & analyze DMV data

[SQL    Server Web Data Administrator](http://www.codeplex.com/SqlWebAdmin) -    Perfect for admin' SQL Server on    shared hosting

Answer (score 1):

Redgate just recently released a really cool (free) plugin to SSMS called [**SQL Server Search**](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Search/index.htm), currently in Beta.  It does a keyword search for any object in your database or server, and is fast.

There's a really cool story behind the development of this tool.  Robert Chipperfield [**blogged about it**](http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/robertchipperfield/archive/2009/11/10/76194.aspx).  Great read.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add to the list [SQL Everywhere](http://www.atlantis-interactive.co.uk/products/sqleverywhere/featureshowcase.aspx) by Atlantis Interactive - even its free edition is very helpful for both database developers and administrators. I liked the most the object search feature and the intellisense, code snippets suport. The tool is very customizable, too.

Answer (score 1):

How about Navicat Lite? it supports SQL Server now

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite how I'd design a SQL UI, but it's reasonable and open source. And it now builds on [win32](http://mail.gnome.org/archives/gnome-db-list/2008-February/msg00008.html)!

```
Package: mergeant
Description: GNOME Database admin tool GUI for GNOME2
 Mergeant is a program which helps administer a DBMS database using the
 gnome-db framework. Basically, it memorizes all the structure of the database,
 and some queries, and does the SQL queries instead of the user (not having to
 type all over again those SQL commands, although it is still possible to do
 so).
```

Answer (score 0):

Web Based Enterprise Manager, haven't used it in a long time.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/vwg-ent-man